# How to find and add libraries from import statements?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I'm working with a code snippet that came with a bunch of import statements, which I copied as well. The problem is that the libraries apparently aren't packaged along with Intellij, so the usual Alt+Enter doesn't help. The IDE shows a "cannot resolve symbol" at almost all of the libraries. Now, I solved one of them by grabbing the correct .jar on the internet somewhere and adding it to the project structure, but I'm having a much harder time locating another one, plus this seems to me like an awfully inefficient way to work.

How do I locate, download, and add the required classes/libraries to the project in an efficient, clean way, based on import statements only?

Imports just for reference:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

Comment: You can use Apache Maven, to configure the dependencies of your project and then they can usually be downloaded automatically. For gson for instance: [Link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2).

Comment: or [gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-gradle.html) which also uses the same [maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-maven.html) style dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out in which jar your class is included. I often use http://www.findjar.com/index.x to help finding it.

Then, you will find the download site for this jar. eg. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm

Then you download it and you include the jar in the classpath of your project. Or you can include the folder where all your jars are in the classpath.

If you find this all too complicated, you can also try to migrate your project to Maven which you will tell the name of the requiered dependencies (easily found online) and it will take care of downloading the jar and include it in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no particular way to do it. If you grabbed the source code from an entire project, I would suggest you to look at the build script. The dependencies would be listed down there.

Else please search for with the FQCN on search engine.
For your imports, I did it for you and found out the source.

- [Apache Log4j 1.2.17](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.zip)
- [google-collections](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0-rc2/google-collections-1.0-rc2.jar)
- [Gson](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/gson-2.6.2.jar)
- [JUnit](http://central.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar)

Hope this helps!

Comment: google-collections is meanwhile called ["guava"](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)